Meaning of ～から照らし合せて見る here
From Kokoro chapter 15:

私は先生のこの人生観の基点に、或る強烈な恋愛事件を仮定してみた。（無論先生と奥さんとの間に起った）。先生がかつて恋は罪悪だといった事から照らし合せて見ると、多少それが手掛りにもなった。

I wonder what ～から照らし合せて見る means here. What から is doing here? Maybe "starting from"? Does 照らし合わせる here mean to compare and contrast many events happened so far to find similarity?

から can be used rather freely to mean "based on ～" or "due to ～":

不注意から骨折してしまった。
自分の経験から言って、恐らく不可能だ。
新たに判明した事実から改めて考えてみよう。
年齢からも難しいと思います。

Your understanding of the meaning of the verb 照らし合わせる itself seems to be fine.
